# Install Spyder with python 3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spyder

As python 2 is reaching end of live very soon, I'm looking for a way to get a usable IDE with python 3 on my raspberry pi (using Raspbian buster). I managed to install Miniconda bundled with python 3 but seem to be unable to install spyder in any environment due to unsolvable package conflicts. I can install spyder using `apt-get`, which points to an old version with python 2.7. My last resort was installing `spyder-kernels` inside my conda envs, but this seems to be impossible due to a conflict with `jupyter-client`. Did anyone manage to get spyder with python 3 on a raspberry?

Comment: Without seeing the error messages indicating what the package conflicts are, it's hard to tell how to solve your problem. Please post those error messages.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Most Anaconda packages are not compiled for ARM, so you can't use that to get Spyder in your Raspberry Pi. You could try to install the `spyder3` package with `apt-get` to see if that works (`spyder3` is the Python 3 version of Spyder).

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To install the Python 3 version of Spyder you need to execute the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```